# Is there a faster way to find co-occurrence of two elements in list of lists

Tags: python, list, count, bigdata

i have a list like this.

```
a = [
    ['a1', 'b2', 'c3'],
    ['c3', 'd4', 'a1'],
    ['b2', 'a1', 'e5'],
    ['d4', 'a1', 'b2'],
    ['c3', 'b2', 'a1']
    ]
```

I'll be given x (eg: 'a1'). I have to find the co-occurrence of a1 with every other element and sort it and retrieve the top n (eg: top 2)
my answer should be

```
[
 {'product_id': 'b2', 'count': 4}, 
 {'product_id': 'c3', 'count': 3}, 
]
```

my current code looks like this:

```
def compute (x):
    set_a = list(set(list(itertools.chain(*a))))
    count_dict = []
    for i in range(0, len(set_a)):
        count = 0
        for j in range(0, len(a)):
            if x==set_a[i]:
                continue
            if x and set_a[i] in a[j]:
                count+=1
        if count>0:
            count_dict.append({'product_id': set_a[i], 'count': count})
    count_dict = sorted(count_dict, key=lambda k: k['count'], reverse=True) [:2]
    return count_dict
```

And it works beautifully for smaller inputs. However my actual input has 70000 unique items instead of 5 (a to e) and 1.3 million rows instead of 5. And hence mxn becomes very exhaustive. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by co-occurance, *exactly*?

Comment: Yeah. If 'a1' and 'b2' have occured in 4 individual lists together, their co-occurrence value is 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the `defaultdict` approach as suggested by @Prune above. Here's the final code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def recommender(input_item, b_list, n):
    count =[]
    top_items = []
    for x in b.keys():
        lst_2 = b[x]
        common_transactions = len(set(b_list) & set(lst_2))
        count.append(common_transactions)
    
    top_ids = list((np.argsort(count)[:-n-2:-1])[1::])
    top_values_counts = [count[i] for i in top_ids]
    
    key_list = list(b.keys())
    for i,v in enumerate(top_ids):
        item_id = key_list[v]
        top_items.append({item_id:  top_values_counts[i]})
    print(top_items)
    return top_items

a = [
        ['a1', 'b2', 'c3'],
        ['c3', 'd4', 'a1'],
        ['b2', 'a1', 'e5'],
        ['d4', 'a1', 'b2'],
        ['c3', 'b2', 'a1']
    ]

b = defaultdict(list) 
for i, s in enumerate(a):
    for key in s : 
        b[key].append(i)
        
input_item = str(input("Enter the item_id: "))
n = int(input("How many values to be retrieved? (eg: top 5, top 2, etc.): "))
top_items = recommender(input_item, b[input_item], n)
```

Here's the output for top 3 for 'a1':

```
[{'b2': 4}, {'c3': 3}, {'d4': 2}]
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

"Faster" is a very general term.  Do you need a shorter total processing time, or shorter response time for a request?  Is this for only one request, or do you want a system that handles repeated inputs?

If what you need is the fastest response time for repeated inputs, then convert this entire list of lists into a graph, with each element as a node, and the edge weight being the number of occurrences between the two elements.  You make a single pass over the data to build the graph.  For each node, sort the edge list by weight.  From there, each request is a simple lookup: return the weight of the node's top edge, which is a hash (linear function) and two direct access operations (base address + offset).

---

UPDATE after OP's response

"fastest response" seals the algorithm, then.  What you want to have is a simple dict, keyed by each node.  The value of each node is a sorted list of  related elements and their counts.

A graph package (say, `networkx`) will give you a good entry to this, but may not retain a node's edges in fast form, nor sorted by weight.  Instead, pre-process your data base.  For each row, you have a list of related elements.  Let's just look at the processing for some row in the midst of the data set; call the elements `a5, b2, z1`, and the dict `d`.  Assume that `a5, b2` is already in your dict.

```
using `intertools`, Iterate through the six pairs.
(a5, b2):
    d[a5][b2] += 1
(a5, z1):
    d[a5][z1]  = 1  (creates a new entry under a5)
(b2, a5):
    d[b2][a5] += 1
(b2, z1):
    d[b2][z1]  = 1  (creates a new entry under b2)
(z1, a5):
    d[z1] = {}      (creates a new z1 entry in d)
    d[z1][a5]  = 1  (creates a new entry under z1)
(z1, b2):
    d[z1][b2]  = 1  (creates a new entry under z1)
```

You'll want to use `defaultdict` to save you some hassle to detect and initialize new entries.

With all of that handled, you now want to sort each of those sub-dicts into order based on the sub-level values.  This leaves you with an ordered sequence for each element.  When you need to access the top `n` connected elements, you go straight to the dict and extract them:

```
top = d[elem][:n]
```

Can you finish the coding from there?

Comment: Hi @Prune! Thanks for your answer. I need a faster response time on request. I'll surely try it out.

Comment: Hi @Prune! Thank you for introducing me to `defaultdict`. The solution worked well.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by @prune it is not mentioned that do you want a shorter processing time or shorter response time.
So I will explain two approach to this problem

1. The optimised code approach (for less processing time)

```
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter

#say we have K THREADS
def compute (x,    top_n=2):
    # first you find the unique items and save them somewhere easily accessible
    set_a = list(set(list(itertools.chain(*a))))


    #first find that in which of your ROWS the x exists
    selected_rows=[]
    for i,row in enumerate(a): #this whole loop can be parallelized
        if x in row: 
            selected_rows.append(i) #append index of the row in selected_rows array
    
    
    # time complexity till now is still O(M*N) but this part can be run in parallel as well, as each row       # can be evaluated independently M items can be evaluated independently 
    # THE M rows can be run in parallel, if we have K threads
    # it is going to take us (M/K)*N time complexity to run it.


    count_dict=[]
    
    
    # now the same thing you did earlier but now in second loop we are looking for less rows
    for val in set_a:
        if val==x:
            continue
        count=0
        for ri in selected_rows: # this whole part can be parallelized as well
            if val in a[ri]:
                count+=1
        count_dict.append({'product_id':val, 'count': count})

    # if our selected rows size on worst case is M itself
    # and our unique values are U, the complexity
    # will be (U/K)*(M/K)*N


    

    res = nlargest(top_n, count_dict, key = itemgetter('count'))
    return res
```

Lets calculate time complexity here
If we have K threads then

```
O((M/K)*N)+O((U/K)*(M/K)*N))
```

where

```
M---> Total rows
N---> Total Columns
U---> Unique Values
K---> number of threads
```

2. Graph approach as suggested by Prune

```
# other approach
#adding to Prune approach
big_dictionary={}
set_a = list(set(list(itertools.chain(*a))))
for x in set_a:
    big_dictionary[x]=[]
    for y in set_a:
        count=0

        if x==y:
            continue
        for arr in a:
            if (x in arr) and (y in arr):
                count+=1
        big_dictionary[x].append((y,count))

for x in big_dictionary:
    big_dictionary[x]=sorted(big_dictionary[x], key=lambda v:v[1], reverse=True)
```

Lets calculate time complexity for this one here
One time complexity will be:

```
O(U*U*M*N)
```

where

```
M---> Total rows
N---> Total Columns
U---> Unique Values
```

But once this big_dictionary is calculated once,
It will take you just 1 step to get your topN values
For example if we want to get top3 values for a1

```
result=big_dictionary['a1'][:3]
```